# iBeacons scanning in background mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ibeacon, ios7.1

Please help me!

Can you explain how can I continue scan iBeacons after changing app mode to background?
Please write an example code (iOS)

Thanks)

Comment: Must need serviceUUID for background scanning BLE/beacons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't indefinitely scan for beacons while backgrounded. You can typically range for about 5 seconds if you detect that you enter a CLBeaconRegion, and you can configure your location manager to notifyEntryStateOnDisplay (it defaults to NO), so when the screen turns on, such as when the user hits the home button, you will get about 5 seconds up range updates then.

Answer (score 0):

The code needed to monitor for beacons is the same whether you are in the background or the foreground.  You set it up like this:

```
 CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]
    initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID
               identifier:identifier];
 [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
```

And then get callbacks to the `locationManager:didEnterRegion:` and `locationManager:didExitRegion:`

You can read more details here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html